# Mosfet output stage with PI controller

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, push-pull

The image below is an output stage I designed for research purposes on my own. It is a PI controlled DC push-pull amplifier. On the left there is a common base circuit with amplification stage (with cascode) after to generate the output stage drive. The simulation looked ok but as always simulation is never the real world. The real curcuit has some overshoot at the output when I input a step function as set voltage. However I can't get rid of it by changing the PI controller parameters. I use OPA288 as real operational amplifier. What do you guys think of that circuit. Any ideas how to get rid of the overshoot at the output?

[image]

**Output voltage in time domain:**

[image]

Comment: Show measurements or waveform for time domain

Comment: Did you consider trace inductance and capacitance? They are not specified and schematic needs improvement.

Comment: if T7 T8 were a few pF that would cause this nonlinear undershoot.  Scrap the design , define specs and redo.

Comment: This is not how to design a high voltage flat response gain amp.

Comment: Any hints how to do it properly without the overshoot. Why does T7,T8 matter so much?

Comment: Scrap the design , define specs

Comment: Before I scrap that design which is working so far (expect the overshoot) I want to understand a bit more. I simulatd with some capacitance between the base and collector of T5 which removes the nonlinear undershoot and te result is an overshoot.